# How do I explode this df so that i have a value for every integer value?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df like this:

```
    Behavior  time
0    a     4
1    b     6
2    c     9
3    a    11
```

How do I explode the data so that I have a value for every integer value (starting with 0, ending with max val in `time`) in the column `time`, repeating `Behavior`. It should look like this:

```
    Behavior  time
0    a     0
1    a     1
2    a     2
3    a     3
4    a     4
5    a     5
6    b     6
7    b     7
8    b     8
9    c     9
10    c    10
11   a    11
```

Comment: You can follow the `reindex` approach in the duplicate, use 0 as starting value and add a `bfill`: `out = df.set_index('time').reindex(range(df['v1'].max()+1), method='ffill').bfill().reset_index()`